# C++ Static member variables

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a class header:

```
class Game {
    static Game instance;
}
```

And I want to set the 'instance' to the "this" object on instantiation, but can't get it to work.

Here's my implementation:

```
Game::Game() {
    Game::instance = this;
}
```

Visual Studio gives a red squiggly thing on the `=`'s operator saying:

```
Error: no operator "=" matches these operands
operands are types are: Game = Game *
```

---

**Update**
I didn't understand the error but I tried changing the assignment code to this:

```
Game::instance = * this;
```

And the error went away.

So, now I'm wondering, what is the difference between those two `assignment` statements?

I think I I sort of know... but an explanation would be nice.

Comment: `this` is a pointer. You have to look up the difference between a pointer to an object of type T and an object of type T.

Comment: Read about pointers and the dereference operator.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're going for the singleton pattern! Search it for some reading. Some people don't like it and I've never had a use for it but if you want it then you'll need more of a framework than you have. Note that `this` doesn't exist until you have created an object.  Also be careful, if you use `=*this` you will be making a copy.

If you want your `instance` to be available from the start of the program then you perhaps should just declare a global instance of the class, it's easier and safer. The singleton pattern is for when you want delayed instantiation or optional instantiation of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
static Game* instance; // a pointer
```

Now `instance` points to the newly created instance.

If you instead do this:

```
Game::instance = *this;
```

`instance` is assigned a 'snapshot' of the current state of the new object. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`instance` is an Object. `this` is a pointer to your current Object. By using `* this`, you are dereferencing your pointer, hence returning the pointee (= the current object)